# How to change the check box (tick box) color to white in android XML

Tags: android, xml

Is there any way to change  the check box (tick box) color to white in android XML. (I need white color tick box which contain black tick, as the preview I got in android studio inside my real device)

Here is my code for check box

```
<CheckBox
    android:textSize="15sp"
    android:textColor="#fff"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Save Loging "
    android:id="@+id/checkBox"
    android:layout_below="@id/PasswordeditText"
    android:checked="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:buttonTint="#fff" />
```

When I add `android:buttonTint="#fff"` preview show the change I need, but it doesn't work in real device

Design preview

[image]

Real Device

[image]

Is there any attribute like `android:buttonTint` which I can use  to achieve the changes in real device.

Comment: Look here, may help:http://stackoverflow.com/a/12889958/3332634

Comment: @yshahak I check with it but it doesn't work for me

Answer (score 65, accepted):

Set the `colorAccent` to your desired color:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat">
    <item name="colorAccent">#fff</item>
</style>
```

Or if you don't want to change your main theme, create a new theme and apply it only to the checkbox:

```
<style name="WhiteCheck">
    <item name="colorAccent">#fff</item>
</style>
```

---

```
<CheckBox
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/WhiteCheck"/>
```

Comment: creating alternative theme with "colorAccent" requires API level 21 and higher!

Comment: @MQoder `colorAccent` is supported by the AppCompat library. `android:colorAccent` would be supported by API 21.

Answer (score 12):

This is variation of tachyonflux's answer:

Try to change buttonTint:

```
<style name="my_checkbox_style">
    <item name="buttonTint">#fff</item>
</style>

<CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/my_checkbox"
            style="@style/my_checkbox_style"
            android:background="#000" />
```

Comment: I have both the buttonTint and the colorAccent items in my style.  Works exactly as expected.  Thanks.

Answer (score 8):

From XML

```
<androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatCheckBox
    ...
    app:buttonTint="@android:color/white" />
```

OR From Java/Kotlin:

```
CompoundButtonCompat.setButtonTintList(cbCheck, ColorStateList.valueOf(Color.WHITE));
```

Answer (score 7):

> easily we can change checkbox color by using this property in xml

```
<CheckBox
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:buttonTint="@color/COLOR_WHICH_YOU_WANT" />
```

Answer (score 1):

1. android:buttonTint="@color/white"  this line of your button color
   change

   ```
             <CheckBox
               android:id="@+id/checkk"
               android:layout_width="wrap_content"
               android:layout_height="@dimen/_40sdp"
               android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
               android:background="@color/black"
               android:buttonTint="@color/white"                 
               android:textSize="@dimen/_14sdp" />
   ```

Answer (score 1):

we can change checkbox color using singe line of code

```
android:buttonTint="@color/app_color" //whatever color
```

Answer (score 1):

With MaterialCheckBox

```
<com.google.android.material.checkbox.MaterialCheckBox
style="@style/checkbox_inv"
android:id="@+id/checkbox"
app:useMaterialThemeColors="false"/>
```

and in stlyles.xml

```
<style name="checkbox_inv">
    <item name="checkedIconTint">@color/blue_gray</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this**

```
<CheckBox
    android:textSize="15sp"
    android:textColor="#fff"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Save Loging "
    android:id="@+id/checkBox"
    android:layout_below="@id/PasswordeditText"
    android:checked="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:button="@android:drawable/checkbox_on_background" />
```

if `CheckBox` checked, else in `android:button=` write `"@android:drawable/checkbox_off_background"`